# Where to put python third-party modules (lxml)?

Tags: python, import, module, lxml, elementtree

I want to write a Python program that makes use of the lxml library (see http://lxml.de/). Of course I want to share my program with others and want to run it on different computers.

Now, I have a folder containing the lxml modules and a python file that does an import. Now, this import does not work and throws an Exception. You can see all the details and an overview in the following image:
http://www.qpic.ws/images/pythonprob.png

Searching for this error, recommendations were to put the path to the lxml source folder in to my PATH. But: I want the program to work on different computers without having to manipulate their PATHes/PYTHONPATHes! The module should just be referenced in a local context, that means, should just reside in a folder next to my program. I think, it does not really matter whether it is lxml or an other third party module collection.

**Am I understanding something bitterly wrong or is there a simple solution to my needs?**

System:
Python 3.3
• Windows 7

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can inject the path using `sys.path.append()`. An alternative would be usig Py2exe or cx_Freeze to bundle the scripts into standalone executable.

Comment: @Blender is right—the usual ways to do this are to use `py2exe` or equivalent, or to just make the user handle it by listing `lxml` as a dependency in your readme. (Needless to say, the latter is much more common for open source projects primarily aimed at linux users, the former for commercial or freeware tools aimed at Windows… and for projects that fall somewhere in between the two, you may have to do both.)

Comment: Thanks, it's good to see there are multiple ways (as almost always in terms of programming) to handle my problem. Mh, I tried sys.path.append(), but surely I used a wrong or misqualified path. How would the actual path look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lxml.etree` is a compiled extension. It is not enough to put the lxml source folder into sys.path.
Try to download `lxml-3.0.2.win-amd64-py3.3.‌exe` from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml, open the installer file with an unzip program, e.g. WinRAR, and replace the current lxml source directory with the lxml folder in the installer.

Answer (score 3):

Install LXML inside a [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), and run your program from that environment. This will handle your PATH issue seamlessly. On different computers, you can build new virtualenvs and install dependencies.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not solve my issue since then I would force every user I distribute the program to to install a virtual environment. I want just to deploy a folder with a program.py in it that can be run.